# ELM : Manage side effect

Tags: elm

isn't **onClick** **(button click**) a side side effect.
in ELM language we can listen for a click event without getting hand dirty with Task and command.

isn't a click event a *side effect* or has *side effect*, if so why we can listen to button click event without using Task

Comment: You don't need a `Task` to listen for messages from DOM elements. Please see the basic [example](http://elm-lang.org/examples/buttons)

Comment: Thank you, you made it clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Elm you don't need Tasks to handle DOM events.

You are absolutely right, user input is a side-effect.

As of `0.17.0`, user input from Html elements is handled behind the scenes in [Html.App](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.0.0/Html-App) and most of DOM events are triggered as messages to your `update` function.

Any HTML element has a type signature of `Html msg`, which hints you towards the idea described above.